# Hammer.js call function after hold event finished

Tags: touch, hammer.js

I'm using Hammer.js in my app, and would like to know how to call a function once the 'Hold' event is finished.

What the best approach to do this?

```
Hammer(element).on("hold", function() {

});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a "release" event that you can attach to the element (https://github.com/EightMedia/hammer.js/wiki/Getting-Started, under the section "Gesture Events").  So, you could have something like:

```
var hammertime = Hammer(element).on("hold", function() {
    console.log("hammer time!");
});

var hammerstop = Hammer(element).on("release", function() {
    console.log("stop!");
});
```